# How can I make custom image path with static_url in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have six images name as **1.jpg** to **6.jpg** of each side of dice and I want to display image defined by a random number I generate in runtime.

How can I make dynamic path including this random number? I tried some ways but getting `404 image not found` only.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Folder with images:

`D:\programs\Django_projects\src\dice\random_dice\static\images`

**Dice** is my project name and **random_dice** is my app name.

I already tried this:

```
<img class="myImage" src='{% static "images/{{ number }}.jpg"%}' alt="can not load the image">
```

and

```
<img class="myImage" style="background-image:url('{{ STATIC_URL }} images/{{ number }}.jpg')" alt="can not load the image">
```

Also tried before the rendering page to make custom name and put in dict but still not working

view.py

```
def home(request):
   X = random.randrange(1, 6)
   result = {
   "number": X,
   "myImage": str(X) + '.jpg'
   }
   return rander(request, 'home.html', result)
```

In that condition ...

```
<img class="myImage" src='{% static "images/{{ myImage }}"%}' alt="can not load the image">
```

And

```
<img class="myImage" style="background-image:url('{{ STATIC_URL }} images/{{ myImage }}')" alt="can not load the image">
```

Should I move image folder to else position or change STATIC_URL or the syntax is wronge? I have no idea please help.

Comment: try moving the `static` folder inside `dice` so your path should look like `D:\programs\Django_projects\src\dice\static`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions:

```
<img class="myImage" src='{% static "images" %}{{ myImage }}' />
```

`static "images"` will prepend "images" with STATIC_URL, `myImage` was taken outside of `{% %}` and now double curly braces work fine.